# When <input type="submit"> is used in the my React component called "App" an error message appears stating "cannot read property 'type' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have to render 3 checkboxes in my page. But when i use the  jsx element in my react componetnt called "App", it gives an error messsage stating "Cannot read property 'type' of undefined".How can i overcome this issue?

```
import React from "react"

function App(){
    return (
       <div>
        <input type="submit"/>
         <p>Placeholder text</p>

        <input type="submit"/>
        <p>Placeholder text</p>

        <input type="submit"/>
        <p>Placeholder text</p>
     </div>
)
}

export default App
```

The error given is  "Cannot read property 'type' of undefined."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the project again using "npm start" command fixes the issue.